# string space convert into - and after that convert into same string how?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I have a string variable

```js
var str = "Air Quality - Indoor"
```

which I converted into

```js
var str2 = str.replace(/-/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()
//air-quality-indoor
```

so how can I convert "air-quality-indoor" into "Air Quality - Indoor" again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Titlecase function taken from [titlecase](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/three-ways-to-title-case-a-sentence-in-javascript-676a9175eb27/) below is a sample code.

```js
let str = "Air Quality - Indoor";
str = transform(str);
console.log(str);
str = transform(str);
console.log(str);

function transform(str) {
  if (str.includes(' ')) {
    return str.replace(/-/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()
  } else {
    return titleCase(str.replace(/-/g, ' ')).replace(/\b(\w+)$/g, '- $1');
  }
}

function titleCase(str) {
  return str.toLowerCase().split(' ').map(function(word) {
    return (word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1));
  }).join(' ');
}
```